# Apply CRST object tracking for 2 cameras with multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, object-tracking

I am trying to apply CRST object tracking with 2 cameras by multithread.
2 cameras will be directly connected in my laptop USB ports separately.
And 2 cameras will be tracking a object in real time.

The first function which is "object_tracking_1" and second one is "object_tracking_2".
And I try to use it with multithread.

If I execute one of any cameras, it works very well.
(The camID : 0(labtop webcam) , 1(camera1) , 2(camera2)  )

My problem:

1. My laptop webcam + one of the connected camera

It can be executed.
But when one is executed with proper object tracking ,
the other one is not working.
I mean I see the window plot to choose box area, but i cannot apply the object tracking.

In other words, both can be executed but one is not working for the object tracking.

2. 2 cameras (main goal)

When I executed it , it is kind of working but the plotted window shows 2 camera's views very fast and alternatively.

And i got this error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18232/2959108515.py", line 59, in object_tracking_1
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.11) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-neg5amx3\opencv\modules\core\src\dxt.cpp:3335: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_64FC2 in function 'cv::dft'
```

On the internet, it says that it is the problem with bus and address with USB, but if i use it one by one, it works perfectly.

Code :

````
```

import cv2
import sys
import threading


(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

def object_tracking_1():
    if __name__ == '__main__' :

        # Set up tracker.
        # Instead of MIL, you can also use

        tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
        tracker_type = tracker_types[7]

        if int(minor_ver) < 3:
            tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
        else:
            if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MIL':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
            if tracker_type == 'KCF':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
            if tracker_type == 'TLD':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
            if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
            if tracker_type == "CSRT":
                tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

        # Read video
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(1) ######################################################
        #video = cv2.VideoCapture("video15.mp4")

        # Exit if video not opened.
        if not video.isOpened():
            print ("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
    
        # Define an initial bounding box
        bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

        # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
        bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

        # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
        ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

        while True:
            # Read a new frame
            ok, frame = video.read()
            if not ok:
                break
        
            # Start timer
            timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    
            # Update tracker
            ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

            # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
            fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
    
            # Draw bounding box
            if ok:
                # Tracking success
                p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])) # bbox[0]=x value,   bbox[1]=y value
                p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))  # x2, y2
                cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
                
                #print(bbox)
                List_x1 = (bbox[0]+bbox[2])/2
                List_y1 = (bbox[1]+bbox[3])/2
                
                RList_x1 = round(List_x1, 2)
                RList_y1 = round(List_y1, 2)
                
                Coordinate_x1 = str(RList_x1)
                Coordinate_y1 = str(RList_y1)
            
                cv2.putText(frame, "x Coordinate : "+ Coordinate_x1 , (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.putText(frame, "y Coordinate : "+ Coordinate_y1 , (100,105), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
            
        
         
            # print('x1=' , RList_x1 , 'y2=' , RList_y1 )
            
  
            
            # X = list(map(str,bbox))
            # print(X)
            # cv2.putText(frame, ", ".join(X) , (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
            else :
            # Tracking failure
                cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
            cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
            cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
            cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)
        

        # Exit if ESC pressed
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
            if k == 27 : break
                

def object_tracking_2():
    if __name__ == '__main__' :

        # Set up tracker.
        # Instead of MIL, you can also use

        tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
        tracker_type = tracker_types[7]

        if int(minor_ver) < 3:
            tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
        else:
            if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MIL':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
            if tracker_type == 'KCF':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
            if tracker_type == 'TLD':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
            if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
            if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
                tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
            if tracker_type == "CSRT":
                tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

        # Read video
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(2) ##################################################
        #video = cv2.VideoCapture("video15.mp4")

        # Exit if video not opened.
        if not video.isOpened():
            print ("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
    
        # Define an initial bounding box
        bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

        # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
        bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

        # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
        ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

        while True:
            # Read a new frame
            ok, frame = video.read()
            if not ok:
                break
        
            # Start timer
            timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    
            # Update tracker
            ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

            # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
            fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
    
            # Draw bounding box
            if ok:
                # Tracking success
                p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])) # bbox[0]=x value,   bbox[1]=y value
                p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))  # x2, y2
                cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
                
                #print(bbox)
                List_x2 = (bbox[0]+bbox[2])/2
                List_y2 = (bbox[1]+bbox[3])/2
                
                RList_x2 = round(List_x2, 2)
                RList_y2 = round(List_y2, 2)
                
                Coordinate_x2 = str(RList_x2)
                Coordinate_y2 = str(RList_y2)
            
                cv2.putText(frame, "x Coordinate : "+ Coordinate_x2 , (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.putText(frame, "y Coordinate : "+ Coordinate_y2 , (100,105), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
            
        
         
            # print('x1=' , RList_x1 , 'y2=' , RList_y1 )
            
  
            
            # X = list(map(str,bbox))
            # print(X)
            # cv2.putText(frame, ", ".join(X) , (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
            else :
            # Tracking failure
                cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
            cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
            cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
            cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)
        

        # Exit if ESC pressed
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
            if k == 27 : break
                

t1 = threading.Thread(target=object_tracking_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=object_tracking_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

# t1.join()
# t2.join()

```
````

My main goal is to apply CRST algorithms for each connected camera.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your webcams   USB 2 or 3

Comment: Sir , you meant camera ID?   webcam : 0,   usb camera1 : 1,  usb camera2 : 2

Comment: no! The version is  webcam USB 2 Or webcam  USB3

Comment: I don't understand..  Would you please explain more clearly?  When I execute the function separately , it works.  What does it mean  "the version"?

Comment: I think toyota Supra is asking the version of the USB standard supported by your cameras. Current versions are USB 2.0 and USB 3.x.

Comment: I think this is not the problem USB version, it's the problem with running the SelecorROI in one window by createROI.  So when I select the box area, there should be 2 windows separately but there is only one plotted window under the name of SelectorROI.  I don't know how i can plot it with changed name since createROI thing is in a built-in function called trackercsrt_create